# Jquery menu: default active DIV container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, submenu

The above-show code works fine excepting the following case. When I open web-page, the content of DIV container is empty and I can see just the navigation menu. Once I press on menu or submenu items, the content is filled with correct data. So, my question is how to use the DIV container 'submenu11' by default? The code line `$active = $('#submenu11').addClass('active');` does not solve this issue.

Look at [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Liana_N/ynVvt/).

Comment: can u add in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: can u come on chat in chat room. i need some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add css to the fiddle? I am not understanding the question completely.

From what I understand you want to show the submenu11 by default right? so I am assuming the rest of the stuff should be hidden which I assume it is done in the css already. your code

```
$active = $('#submenu11').addClass('active');
```

does not do anything because you are assigning it to $active

I think you are looking for something like this maybe?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submenu11').addClass('active');
});
```

this is assuming all your css classes are defined correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //code for ajax calling

    $('#submenu11').addClass('active').trigger('click);
});
```

Comment: can u come on chat in chat room. i need some clarification.